# CometD-Publish/Deliver JSONObject and transfer it to POJO but stucked

Tags: java, json, cometd

I am new to CometD and I was successfully building it which passes value with `Map<String, Object>`. However, when I want to pass value with POJO(of course in JSON way), the problem occurs.

I am now publish JSONObject from Client and the Server will directly deliver the data back, so the Client will receive the data it published:

**POJO to be published** (Simply POJO with 2 elements and corresponding getter/setter) **:**

```
public class TestObject {

int pxid;
boolean isInService;  

public TestObject() {
}

public TestObject(int pxid, boolean isInService) {
    this.pxid = pxid;
    this.isInService = isInService;
}
//getters and setters below...
}
```

**In Server Side**(Simply deliver the data back to the Client)**:**

```
public EchoService(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer) {
    super(bayeuxServer, "echo");
    addService("/echo", "processEcho"); 
}

public void processEcho(ServerSession remote, Map<String, Object> data) {
    System.out.println("in PROCESSECHO"+data.toString());
    remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/echo", data, null);
}
```

**In Client:**

```
public void createObjAndSend(){        
    TestObject newPX1 = new TestObject(5, false);        
    JSONObject pxJsonObj=JSONObject.fromObject(newPX1);
    sendMsgInJson(pxJsonObj,NODE_CHANNEL);
}

private void sendMsgInJson(JSONObject jsonObj, String channel) {
    ClientSessionChannel nodeChannel = client.getChannel(channel);
    nodeChannel.publish(jsonObj, new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel csc, Message msg) {
            if (!msg.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("not published ok.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("published ok");
            }
        }
    });
}

private class NodeLsnr implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel csc, Message msg) {

        String JSONstr = msg.getJSON();
        System.out.println("Receive JSON:"+JSONstr);
        JSONObject jsonObj =  JSONObject.fromObject(JSONstr);
        System.out.println("jsonObj:" +jsonObj.toString());

    }
}
```

It works fine until the Client receive the data it passed to Server.
In the method `onMessage` in the `NodeLsnr` inner class,it do print the `JSONstr` like:

> *Receive JSON:{"data":{"isInService":false,"pxid":5},"channel":"/echo"}*

However, it's stuck when I want to transfer JSON string to JSONObject with this line:

> JSONObject jsonObj =  JSONObject.fromObject(JSONstr);

When I say "stuck", I mean there's no Exception nor the jsonObj printed(as I wanted), instead, it happens nothing.
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I DID study the official site of the CometD like [this](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/java_json.html), but I can't understand it well.
If my approach wan't make sense, what is the correct/suggest way?

---

### Update

Instead of

> JSONObject jsonObj =  JSONObject.fromObject(JSONstr);

, I also tried

> JSONObject jsonObj=(JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( JSONstr );

but still in vain...

Comment: P.S. I'm using  net.sf.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just when I get rid of cometd and simply transfer JSON string to JSONObject, it throws Exception.

It turns out that the library `commons-lang-1.0.1.jar` I imported  was too old.
After I import `commons-lang-2.6.jar` and delete `commons-lang-1.0.1.jar`, everything's fine.

Note that though I have imported `commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar` earlier, it still won't work at all. I think it's because the comman-lang after 3.0 use a different package as [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) said:

> Note that Lang 3.0 (and subsequent versions) use a different package (org.apache.commons.lang3) than the previous versions (org.apache.commons.lang), allowing it to be used at the same time as an earlier version.

However, it's weird that it didn't throw any Exception while integrated with cometd, maybe it's catched by glassfish?